# combine exec and select into single query

Tags: sql, exec, union

I need to combine these into a single query, how do I do that I tried Union maybe I'm doing it wrong. Someone suggested I try using a temp table but not sure how I've used temp table maybe once in my entire life. I'd assume you create a table and do a insert of some sort but what about the exec of the proc?

```
    DECLARE
@VendorName AS NVARCHAR(100) = 'DOGWOOD TRUCKING',
@Commodity AS NVARCHAR(100) = 'WASTE',
@GLAccount AS NVARCHAR(20),
@CostCenter AS NVARCHAR(20),
@InternalOrderNum AS NVARCHAR(20),
@BeginDate AS DATE = '3/1/2016',
@EndDate AS DATE = '3/31/2016'

DECLARE
    @InvoiceDate AS NVARCHAR(10) = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) AS [MM/DD/YYYY])

SELECT TOP 1
    Vendor_Name,
    Vendor_Address,
    Vendor_City,
    Vendor_State,
    Vendor_Zip_Code,
    ISNULL(Vendor_Email, ' ') AS 'Vendor_Email',
    ISNULL(Vendor_Phone_1, ' ') AS 'Vendor_Phone',
    Vendor_SAP_Num,
    @InvoiceDate AS 'Invoice_Date',
    @BeginDate AS 'Invoice_Start_Date',
    @EndDate AS 'Invoice_End_Date'
FROM 
    dbo.List_Vendors 
WHERE 
    Vendor_Name = @VendorName

EXEC [dbo].[VB_Truck_Report_Sell_Invoice] @VendorName, @Commodity, @BeginDate, @EndDate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need an UNION query. I guess you need to put it toghether. Maybe I'm wrong but hope it helps:

```
DECLARE
@VendorName AS NVARCHAR(100) = 'DOGWOOD TRUCKING',
@Commodity AS NVARCHAR(100) = 'WASTE',
@GLAccount AS NVARCHAR(20),
@CostCenter AS NVARCHAR(20),
@InternalOrderNum AS NVARCHAR(20),
@BeginDate AS DATE = '3/1/2016',
@EndDate AS DATE = '3/31/2016'

DECLARE
    @InvoiceDate AS NVARCHAR(10) = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) AS [MM/DD/YYYY])

SELECT TOP 1
    Vendor_Name,
    Vendor_Address,
    Vendor_City,
    Vendor_State,
    Vendor_Zip_Code,
    ISNULL(Vendor_Email, ' ') AS 'Vendor_Email',
    ISNULL(Vendor_Phone_1, ' ') AS 'Vendor_Phone',
    Vendor_SAP_Num,
    @InvoiceDate AS 'Invoice_Date',
    @BeginDate AS 'Invoice_Start_Date',
    @EndDate AS 'Invoice_End_Date,
    @Commodity,
    @GLAccount,
    @CostCenter,
    @InternalOrderNum,
    @BeginDate,
    @EndDate,
    @InvoiceDate
FROM 
    dbo.List_Vendors 
WHERE 
    Vendor_Name = @VendorName
```

Then you will have it all together.

Hope it helps, just tell me wheter i'm wrong to help you.